# node webkit text to speech api not working?

Tags: javascript, webkit, node-webkit

I am trying to build an app with node webkit which is running in chrome browser well and some text to speech api is not working properly in node webkit (windows). When i did some checks in console with webkit debugger i can see the

```
   speechSynthesis.getVoices()
```

doesnt have any voices. how to fix this ?

```
    var voiceOutput = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance("sample message");
    voiceOutput.voice = speechSynthesis.getVoices()[0];
    speechSynthesis.speak(voiceOutput);
```

Comment: i am using latest version of node webkit for windows 32 bit....

Answer (score 0):

Node-webkit or nw.js does not support the SpeechSynthesis API.

I also came across this problem, while developing my own personal assistant.(You give it voice commands and it does stuff for you :D )

I found dictate.js for speech to text .

In order to implement the text to speech feature i recommend you use the google translate API.

An example of the google text to speech API :

http://translate.google.com/translate_tts?tl=en&q=Hello

The two above solved my problems for TTS (text to speech) and STT (speech to text) in node-webkit.

Note: Google Translate API only allows up to 100 characters per request. So if you have a big/lengthy text that needs to be converted to speech, you must break it down into sentences of 100 characters, while preserving whole words, and punctuation.

Hope this helped!
Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I rencently try to create an app for blind using NW and I came across the same issue. You can look at https://github.com/nwjs/nw.js/issues/1661.

**For production build (win64)** : it works fine, using the system voices (Narrator).

**For development (archlinux)** : In **run** mode on linux, I have to use [Cylon Speech](https://cylonjs.com/documentation/platforms/speech/) to plug system voices into speechSynthesis. Then, I launch nw command with this flags to enable speech :

```
nw . --enable-speech-dispatcher
```

With this method, I can have tts both on linux (for dev) and windows (for users) working fine.